# Xray license support detection

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

Does Xray from Jfrog has support for expression-type license violation detection in NuGet packages? Or is it just for custom types using  .txt or md files?

Answer (score 1):

Xray reads .nuspec file and should detect expression-type licenses from this file as well as license.txt file and license.md file (As in most package types)

If you encounter a different Behavior please let me know about it.

Comment: Testing it I noticed that just trigger violation of watched polices by md and txt files  not expression type @dor-tambour